# How to draw gradient background the same as the UINavBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to draw gradient background the same as the UINavBar?

I want add some views on the UINavBar with the same background.  They drop shadow, so I cannot simply set them transparent.

==============================

I got the solution, very simple

```
+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [CAGradientLayer class];
}

//
// setupGradientLayer
//
// Construct the gradient for either construction method
//
- (void)setupGradientLayer
{
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = (CAGradientLayer *)self.layer;
    gradientLayer.colors =
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor,
            (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0.69 green:0.74 blue:0.8 alpha:1.0].CGColor,
            (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0.43 green:0.51 blue:0.63 alpha:1.0].CGColor,
            (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.3 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0].CGColor,
        nil];
    gradientLayer.locations = 
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],
            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.02],
            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.98],
            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1],
        nil];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by creating a CAGradientLayer in your custom view.

You cand find documentation about this here: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html